# How to pass and interpret a complex render context in Django?

Tags: django

I'm pretty new to Django and am not sure if I'm approaching this problem correctly. My view code generates a many to many map. So something like

```
{'penguin' : ("bird", "black", "flightless", "arctic")},
{'axolotl' : ("reptile", "green")}
{'rhino' : ("mammal", "horn", "heavy")}
and so on... for a lot of different procedurally generated animals
```

Out of this I'm trying to render page that would just have the animal's name and underneath it a few bullet points with the characteristics, like this

---

Penguin

bird

black

flightless

---

and so on for every animal. The number of these animals and the descriptions are unknown and are parsed at runtime from an xml file

I thought I could just pass this structure into the template and use the template language to iterate over it and render it out, but so far I feel like I'm having to jump through hoops, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is just outside the scope of Django and I should be using a different framework for this kind project.

The problems I'm running into: I'm having issues figuring out how to even pass this structure into the context and have it available for the template to use. So far I have this in the view code:

```
    animal_name_list = ()
    characteristics_map = {}
    for animal in xmlFileAnimals:
        characteristics_map[len(animal_name_list)] = animal.chars //gets a list of characteriscs of the animal as a list
        animal_name_list.append(animal.name)
```

So now I have an animal name list and a two dimensional array, characteristics_map that gives me the characteristics of an animal based on the offset of the animal in its own list so it looks like this:

```
characteristics_map[0] = (bird, black ...)
characteristics_map[1] = (reptile, ...)
...
```

I then pass this into context as a list and a map like so:

```
context = {"names_list":animalNames, "char_map":characteristics_map}
```

In the template I wanted to just do something like

```
for(uint i = 0; i < names_list.size(); i++)
{
    print(names_list[i] + " has the following characteristics ");
    for (uint j = 0; j < char_map[i].length(); j++)
    {
      print(char_map[i][j] + "/n");
    }
}
```

But I can't find any way to get this done in the template language. If anyone could offer any suggestions on how I could get this implemented in templates or how to change the code so that most of this happens in the view I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first register a template filter to get the index of list like this:

templatetags/get_index.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_index(my_list, index):
     return my_list[index]
```

and then you can use loop and consume that filter in your template like this:

```
{% for animal in names_list %}
    <h3> {{ animal }} </h3>
    <ul>
      {% for character in char_map|get_index:forloop.counter0 %}
         <li> {{ character }} </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    
{% endfor %}
```